# iOS - iPad background image is getting cut off short

Tags: ios, ipad

I have an iPad/iPhone app and the iPhone background looks fine, but when I use the same image for the iPad version, it looks like it is getting cut off in the middle of the page.

Here is a screen shot:

[image]

The image is called buildings.png and I have 2 versions of it, the buildings.png and the buildings@2x for the iPad.

The way I get the image to render in the background is from the code like this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"building"];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
```

What would be the best way for me to fix this issue of the image being cut off like that on the iPad view?

Thanks!

Comment: are you checking what device you are on?  then loading the appropriate image?

Comment: @own gerig I am not certain actually. I think it might not be loading the ipad image. But I am not sure how to check.

Comment: if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        //load iphone image
    } else {
        //load ipad image
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `colorWithPatternImage` is the reason your image is getting cut like that. Why not create a `UIImageView` to contain your image, add it on your view and call `[self.view sendSubviewToBack:yourImageView]` ?

EDIT
Here is your code snippet

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"building"]];
imgView.frame = self.view.bounds; // to set the frame to your view's size
[self.view addSubview:imgView];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:imgView];
```

Comment: hmmm interesting. Didn't realize it could be the colorWithPatternImage ....Could you please post how the snippet would look like the way you are suggesting? I don't have too much experience dealing with images so I am a bit confused.  Thanks!

Comment: I just tried this: UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:@"building"];
    imgView.frame = self.view.bounds; // to set the frame to your view's size
    [self.view addSubview:imgView];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:imgView]; and that didn't quite work. Plus on the first line I get a warning that I have incompatible types of NSString and image

Comment: You have to pass an image object not a string... I changed my code for you

Comment: thank you, but on the second line, it gives an error about the img.frame reference - where did you get that object?

Comment: that worked...yeah I figured it was a typo, but I just wanted to make sure..  thank you :)

Comment: btw quick question...now that the image is bigger, it is a big visibly blurry..is there something that can be done to the image so that it is less blurry on the ipad?

Comment: what do you mean it is bigger ? It should have the same size as before... If the image is blurry it's probably because it doesn't have the proper resolution...

Comment: yeah it is a problem with the resolution.  On the ipad view, the image gets pixelated and does not look as sharp.  Is there anything that should/can be done to make the image less pixelated on the ipad? Should I adjust something in the original image?

Comment: Are you sure you included the @2x image in your project ?

Answer (score -1):

This is what worked for me -

UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];

imgView.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]; // to set the frame to your view's size

[self.view addSubview:imgView];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:imgView];